# About Plane motion

Tags: kinematics, geometry

An excerpt from a book I read:

> “In reality, objects are moving in a 3-dimensional space. However, if the acceleration of the object is constant, then there must be a certain plane which contains the initial velocity vector and the acceleration vector. (In Geometry two straight lines define a plane. Here the two lines are the acceleration and the initial velocity.) After that, the motion becomes a 2-dimensional problem, because the object has no velocity and acceleration components perpendicular to the plane. In other words, the motion of the object is confined to the plane.”

I really do not understand the concept of a plane. What are “components” perpendicular to a plane? I see the 3D vector in physics as a moving object which has a height, width and length. So I don’t see how the object can be “always within a plane” with respect to initial velocity vector and acceleration vector. By the way, I don’t understand how acceleration and velocity can be a vector either (if they can, what do their components ijk respectively represent?)

Can anyone explain that from the most fundamental to me? I’m very new to this subject. Thanks!

Comment: Which book? Please cite your sources, it can obviously only help!

Comment: First, do you understand that a plane (flat 2D surface) can exist in a 3D space?

Comment: But honestly, this is really the math I've done in ninth and tenth class, which is fine, not everyone went to the same school system as I did, but it means you will really have to define your background for us. The answer we give someone in eighth grade might look different to that we give someone who's been in construction for a decade!

Comment: It is actually a self learnt booklet for Hong Kong Physics Olympiad (HKPhO), so never mind that. I’m currently in form 3 in HK, equivalent to Year 9, but haven’t learnt mechanics yet. Just self learning. My background: I should say I have a decent understanding in vectors, and I know a plane can exist in a 3D surface (but I do not know how the it can apply to acceleration and velocity). I know what is acceleration and velocity (I have a decent understanding of Calculus 1) but I fails to understand the concept of plane as stated above.

Comment: Okay. Now can you imagine an object in (straight line) motion restricted to this 2D plane in 3D space?

Comment: Yes I can imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Physical Quantities are primarily of two types, vectors and scalars, vector quantities need direction and magnitude both to be specified, scalar quantities are sufficiently described by magnitude alone. Distance between two points is fully described by *magnitude* of length which has to be travelled to reach from one point to another, hence it's a scalar. While Displacement is a vector, suppose you have a body at point A in 3D co-ordinate system, after body underwent motion it was found at point B, the straight vector with it's tail at  A and head at B is a displacement vector or simply a position vector. Position vector shows distance of body from tail of vector as well as direction in which the body is located relative to reference point.

Velocity is first derivative of position vector and acceleration the second derivative of it. Since position is a vector, its derivative is also a vector, and it has the same direction as the displacement. Hence velocity is a vector. Magnitude of velocity is called speed. Since velocity is a vector, its derivative is also a vector, and it has the direction of the change in velocity. Hence acceleration too is a vector and it is directed along the direction of change of velocity.

The components of velocity and acceleration vectors specify the rates of change of position and velocity along the coordinate axes, respectively. For example, if the position vector is $$\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$$, then the velocity vector is $$\vec{v}=(v_x,v_y,v_z)$$, where $$v_x=\frac{dx}{dt}$$, $$v_y=\frac{dy}{dt}$$, and $$v_z=\frac{dz}{dt}$$. Similarly, the acceleration vector is $$\vec{a}=(a_x,a_y,a_z)$$, where $$a_x=\frac{dv_x}{dt}=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$, $$a_y=\frac{dv_y}{dt}=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$$, and $$a_z=\frac{dv_z}{dt}=\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}$$. The components of these vectors can be positive, negative, or zero, depending on the direction of motion and the choice of coordinate system.

There is no truly 2D interaction possible practically, every physical interaction occur in 3D but for sake of simplicity it's often convenient to simplify the system to 2D plane. To do this we only consider the coplanar vectors neglecting any vector going outside the plane. It's like we are doing analysis of carrom board, every interaction on carrom board is confined to two dimensional plane, pieces generally don't move above or below the plane (expect when they fall in hole or are hit very hard making them topple or fly outside board).

For example, a ball thrown at an angle, a car turning around a curve, or a satellite orbiting the earth are examples of motion in a plane.

To analyze motion in a plane, we need to use vector quantities, such as displacement, velocity, and acceleration, which have both magnitude and direction. We can represent these vectors by their components along the X and Y axes, using trigonometry and the Pythagorean theorem.

If the acceleration of an object is constant, then the object's motion can be simplified by finding a plane that contains both the initial velocity vector and the acceleration vector. This plane is called the **trajectory plane** of the object. The trajectory plane is unique, because any two non-parallel vectors define a plane. The object will always move within this plane, because it has no component of velocity or acceleration perpendicular to it. This means that we can treat the motion as a two-dimensional problem, and use the equations of motion separately for the X and Y components.

For example, consider a projectile launched at an angle from the ground with an initial velocity of $v_0$ and an acceleration of $-g$ (due to gravity) along the Y axis. The trajectory plane of the projectile is the vertical plane that contains the initial velocity vector and the acceleration vector. The projectile will follow a parabolic path within this plane, and its motion can be described by the following equations:

$$v_x=v_0\cos\theta$$
$$v_y=v_0\sin\theta-gt$$
$$x=v_0\cos\theta t$$
$$y=v_0\sin\theta t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$

Where $\theta$ is the angle of launch, $t$ is the time, and $x$ and $y$ are the horizontal and vertical displacements of the projectile.

Working out realistic problems on kinematics for 1D then 2D and then 3D may help you properly grasp the ideas which will take lot of time to understand theoretically. By my experience Problems in general physics by Irodov is very nice book to solve such problems.

Comment: Thanks so much. Understand a lot better now. But still one confusion: why “If the acceleration of an object is constant, then the object's motion can be simplified by finding a plane that contains both the initial velocity vector and the acceleration vector.” ?

Comment: @SamuelTse please ask your doubt precisely...

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of the question. It is that I don’t understand why an object’s motion in 3D can be simplified only when the acceleration of an object is constant.

Comment: if acceleration is not constant, then the velocity changes at a variable rate, and the motion becomes more complicated to analyze. it's not necessary condition but reduces complexity.

Comment: Thanks so much!